# How can i change the order of comments?

Tags: comments, order

I like to have the latest comment shown above. Just under the post. Now the oldest comment is shown. How can i change the order?

With regards,

Albert

Comment: Please show us what you already tried (in code).

Answer (score 1):

In `wp-admin` go to `wp-admin/options-discussion.php` and change the setting:

> [image]